# how to click enter to trigger search

Tags: excel, web, triggers, command, vba

I would like to add a piece of code that automatically presses Enter after the code has been added into the search form.

The url is the following one:
http://www.nook.com/gb/store/books

My code so far (it doesn't work since I dont see the code in the search box..)

Selection.Copy

IE.Document.getElementByid("_skeyword ").Value = ActiveCell.Value

I am very new at coding so any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

When we click enter it simply does get request by navigating to URL. Try below code.

```
Sub SearchBook()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://www.nook.com/gb/store/books"

    Dim bookname As String
    bookname = "visions trips and crowded rooms"


    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate URL
    IE.Visible = True


    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    MsgBox "Site will now search for book"

    IE.navigate "http://www.nook.com/gb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%5Bs%5Dkeyword=" & bookname

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, thank you for coming back to me on this one. What I was trying to do is the following: Dim IE As Object
    Dim x As Integer
         
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    

    IE.Navigate "http://www.nook.com/gb/store/books"
    IE.Visible = True
    apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
    
    While IE.busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

Comment: ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times. 'Here it goes to my excel file and takes the code (ISBN)
    For x = 1 To NumRows
         
         ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
    Selection.Copy
    IE.Document.getElementByid("_skeyword ").Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Application.SendKeys "~"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Comment: Basically I need to place the ISBN in the search field and trigger the command Enter automatically so that I can go the book's page. Thank you in advance for you patience and time!